# Condition with char does not work in C

Tags: c, if-statement, char, scanf

I've got a weird issue. Tried to use a if-statement and a do-while loop to validate my condition in case of the char variable is not equal to 'c' and 'f' but when I chose 'c' or 'C' or 'f' or 'F' still displaying "Wrong Choice" Following the part that does not work. I tracked printing the variable (as you can see the `printf()` code bellow commented) when I type 'c' I can see that the program accepted 'c' but still displaying as wrong input.
I've called `#include<stdio.h>` and `#include<ctype.h>` already.
Anyone can help me?

```
char choice;

do
{
    printf("\nChoose between Celsius (c) or for Fahrenheit (f):");
    scanf(" %c*%c", &choice);

    //printf("\nchoice1: %c", choice);

    choice = tolower(choice);

    //printf("\nchoice2: %c", choice);

    if(choice != 'c' || choice != 'f')
        printf("\nWrong choice!!");

}while(choice!='c' || choice!='f');
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the choice is, it will be unequal to `c` or unequal to `f`. If it's equal to `c`, it's unequal to `f`. If it's equal to `f`, it's unequal to `c`. So both of your conditions will always be true.

You want `choice != 'c' && choice != 'f'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(choice != 'c' || choice != 'f')
```

will result true for all `choice`, it should be

```
if(choice != 'c' && choice != 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
if(choice != 'c' && choice != 'f')
      printf("\nWrong choice!!");
```